# While loop repeat for Game

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I am trying to get my game to return to the user the word 'correct'. It does that however after the correct answer is given the while loop stops. How do I get it so that it continues and breaks when the answer is 'correct'
Here is the 1st part of the code

```
#imported libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 
import random 

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-followed_Instagram_accounts'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(StringIO(page.text), 'html') 
#clean table and dataset
for t in soup.select('[title="Yes"]'):
    t.replace_with("Yes")
df = pd.read_html(page.text)[0]
df = df.drop(index=(50))
df['Followers (millions)'] = df['Followers (millions)'].astype(float)
#List of names
column_names = list(df.columns)
#While loop to run the game
answer = ''
count  = 0
```

This is the While loop used to run the game

```
while True:
    count+=1
    if count == 2:
        break 
    index = 0
    def randomIndexValue(): #random Index Value generator
        global index 
        index = random.randint(1,49)
        return(index)


    #Select and print Neymar, a footballer, from brasil.
    #have one stament w followers and compare it to another 
    randomIndexValue()
    item_A = [df.iloc[index][column_names[1]], df.iloc[index][column_names[2]], df.iloc[index][column_names[5]], df.iloc[index][column_names[6]], df.iloc[index][column_names[4]]]
    print(f'Compare A: {item_A[1]} is a {item_A[2]} from {item_A[3]} and has {item_A[4]} million followers')

    randomIndexValue()
    item_B= [df.iloc[index][column_names[1]], df.iloc[index][column_names[2]], df.iloc[index][column_names[5]], df.iloc[index][column_names[6]], df.iloc[index][column_names[4]]]
    print(f'Compare B: {item_B[1]} is a {item_B[2]} from {item_B[3]} and has {item_B[4]} million followers')
# Check which comparison is more popular 
    if max(item_A[4],item_B[4]) == item_A[4]:
        answer = 'A'
        print(f'item A which is {item_A[1]} has more followers than item B {item_B[1]}') 
    elif max(item_A[4],item_B[4]) == item_B[4]: 
        answer = 'B'
        print(f'item B which is {item_B[1]} has more followers than item A {item_A[1]}')
    
    score = 0
    question = input('Which option is more popular?\nA or B: ').upper()    
    
    if question == answer: 
        print('Correct!')
        score += 1 * 100
        continue
    elif question != answer: 
        print("Incorrect")

print(f'you scored: {score}')
```

i tried editing the IF statement to add 'continue' however the same problem persist.

```
    if question == answer: 
        print('Correct!')
        score += 1 * 100
        continue
    elif question != answer: 
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: Hi Yas! Have you ever used the debug function of your IDE? e.g. setting break points, stepping through your code line by line etc

Comment: specifically, I'd put a break point on the line `count+=1`

Comment: Omg thank you I figured it out

Comment: Yas write a short answer if you want :-)